# Display Wordpress Parent Category with siblings and current category posts

Tags: wordpress, navigation, categories

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:
[image]

This is for a sidebar navigation. When the visitor is on the subcategory I need the subcategory to display the current posts under that category and also the sibling subcategories. This structure will also have to work at the post level as well.

When the visitor is at the category level - I have it set up so that the user is only able to see the subcategories under that category - which is what I need exactly. I'm just trying to sort out the subcategory template (which is its own template - separate from the category template).

If there’s a plugin that addresses this issue quickly, I’m all for it. Right now I’m just trying to use wp_list_categories with no luck. I appreciate all your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
 $taxonomy_name = 'products-category';

$args = array(
    'type' => 'products',
    'orderby'          => 'name',
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'taxonomy'       => $taxonomy_name,
    'parent' => '0',
    'hide_empty' => 0
); 

 $categories = get_categories( $args ); 


foreach($categories as $category){
echo   $category->name;
echo  $term_id =  $category->term_id.'<br>';


$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

         // Note : Here is your Post loop using term id 


}
echo '</ul>';


}
?>
```

Good Luck

Comment: The children being displayed need to be posts, not categories. Is it possible to display both the subcategories and have the active subcategory displaying the posts underneath it? Thank you for your help!